# Is there a singleTile option in open layers 3?

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

In previous versions, there was a singleTile option (for OpenLayers.Layer.WMS) to avoid labels and features cut along tile borders and repeated labels.

Open layers 3 does not seem to have this option and some layers do not show at certain zoom levels.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use ol.layer.Image with ol.source.ImageWMS instead

Comment: That works and the labels show at all some levels. However; I need to use ol.source.TileWMS for other reasons. So I guess my question would be how can I make the label show at all some levels? Thx

Comment: I'm failing to understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: It's ok, I will open a different post for that. Thanks!

Comment: Add some screenshots if you do to explain the issue.